# partial class methods in node.js using lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, lodash

I would like to create a function in node.js which takes an integer value and converts it into a binary string using lodash/underscore's `_.partial`/`_.partialRight`.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var n = 123456789;
console.log(n.toString(2)); // works
console.log(Number.prototype.toString.call(n, 2)); // works

var toBin = _.partialRight(Number.prototype.toString.call, 2);
console.log(toBin(n)); // broken
console.log(toBin); // --> [Function: bound]
```

The last broken implementation produces:

```
/media/data/Dropbox/game-of-spell/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957
        return func.apply(thisBinding, args);
                    ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

**Is it possible to partialise `.call` or `.apply`? If not why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what's happening you should try to do this:

```
var call = Number.prototype.toString.call;
call(2);
```

You will get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. You are thinking that `call` is a function, and the error is wrong. Yes, `call` is a function but this TypeError is not talking about `call`, it's talking about it's context(`this`). This is gonna be confusing, but function `call` when called, will call it's context/this obejct.

You can basically do this:

```
call.call(function (a) { console.log('wat? This: ', this, '  argument:', a); }, { thisObject: true }, 'im arguemnt');
```

Which will result in this: `wat? This:  Object {thisObject: true}   argument: im arguemnt`

But when `call` is called without any context or this object, then the default this object will be `window` or `global` object or `null` in strict mode. You can verify the default this object like this:

```
function verify() { return this; }; console.log(verify());
```

Which will print global object in node and window object in browsers.

**To fix your problem**, you have to bind it to it's parent function:

```
var toString = Number.prototype.toString;
var call = toString.call.bind(toString);
```

Or using lodash bind:

```
var call = _.bind(toString.call, toString);
```

Then this will work:

```
var toBin = _.partialRight(call, 2);
```

You can also shorten it to `var toBin = _.partialRight(toString.call.bind(toString), 2);`

If you want to use `_.partial`, then use bind directly:

```
var print1000 = _.bind(toString.call, toString, 1000);
console.log(print1000(), print1000(2), print1000(8), print1000(16));
```

You also might wonder why `Number.prototype.toString.call(n, 2)`. Because when you call a function as a method of an object(actually a function in here), it will take the object as it's context.

You can read more in this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11523378/774086).